# How do I separate Hyperlinks on HTML collapse list?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

I have a code which gives me a list of different articles in my site. I would like to be able to link each one to a point in my page. This is what I have so far...I'm not a programmer by any stretch of the imagination so any help would be greatly appreciated.

As it stands just now, the top collapse and link are the only ones which work. The other ones aren't being picked up or recognised. Last one takes you to Reddit but doesn't collapse.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

```
<html>
 <head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <style>
     .collapsible {
       background-color: #005B4F;
       color: white;
       cursor: pointer;
       padding: 18px;
       width: 100%;
       border: none;
       text-align: left;
       outline: none;
       font-size: 15px;
     }

     .active, .collapsible:hover {
       background-color: #00B528;
     }

     .content {
       padding: 0 18px;
       max-height: 0;
       overflow: hidden;
       transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
       background-color: #f1f1f1;
     }
   </style>
 </head>
  <body>

   <h2>Contents</h2>
   <button class="collapsible">A Message From Our Operations Manager - Gill Grant</button>
   <div class="content">
     <p><a href="https://sites.google.com/johnlewis.co.uk/issue309thoct2019/the-essentials#h.p_UtsjfkFFUDa7"> Welcome To This Week's Newsletter</p>
   </div>
   <div>
     <button class="collapsible">Headlines</button>
     <div class="content">
       <p><a></br> href="https://sites.google.com/johnlewis.co.uk/issue309thoct2019/the-essentials#h.p_xxaZ53cPzgEW"> Teleopti - Issues, Feedback &amp; Action</p>
     </div>
     <button class="collapsible">Customer Area</button>
     <div class="content">
       <p><a href= https://sites.google.com/johnlewis.co.uk/issue309thoct2019/the-essentials#h.p_vcv7X_qd3y7C> Gift Update</p>
     </div>
     <button class="collapsible">Staff Area</button>
     <div class="content">
       <p><a href= https://sites.google.com/johnlewis.co.uk/issue309thoct2019/the-essentials#h.p_tIP4bMaCaClp> Staff Rewards </br>
         <a href= https://sites.google.com/johnlewis.co.uk/issue309thoct2019/the-essentials#h.p_6NMC5GiOaRcs> Autumn Beauty Box </br>
     </div>

  <script>

    var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
      coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.maxHeight){
          content.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
      });
    }
  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome on Stackoverflow. You need to reed Anchor links for make you want. Please reed this : https://html.com/anchors-links/

Answer (score 0):

You have sections on your page I gather with content, that you want displayed or hidden based on which button is clicked. In you *content* `div`s, move the different sections into them, not the links, but the html itself on your page.

The script at then end of the page, what's its doing is:

(1) grabs all elements with a `collapsible` class. So that's all the nav buttons applicable.

(2) assigns an event listener so that when a button is clicked, the element immediately following it (that's it's `<div class="content">`) is then displayed; which is done by setting it's height.

All you need to do is place your actual html content per section in the appropriate `<div class="content">...</div>` and let the script and its css take care of the rest.

Comment: Hi GetSet, I've edited the code again. Apologies, I was trying to make it generic but to be honest no-one should be able to access it outside our organisation anyway. I have sections with content and all I want it to do is jump to the part of the page I link it to. Any ideas using the new code?

Comment: Ok. With that said, it's best not to make any further changes without first understanding what is going on by that little end of page script on your page. I will update my answer with some insights on that. From there you will be able to better get the gist of my original answer.